# Issue with upload.php with media

Tags: uploads, media

I'm having trouble uploading any images, files etc... on to the CMS. When visiting the Media Library the loading spinner will just constantly load without anything being loaded up. When I do it just returns with the error "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later." However, visiting the Upload folder the image is uploaded and with the additional sizes associated with the image as well.

I've tried a few things already to try and fix it but havent had any success and I even tried downloading a fresh Wordpress install which hasn't worked either! I appreciate this question has already been asked however these questions seem to be quite dated and an up-to-date answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already start [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and check the server logs (probably by contacting the hoster)?

Comment: Sorry should have clarified that its just being hosted on localhost for the moment using WAMP. Using Firefox and checking the Network tab in the Inspector its coming up with a success message